# Javascript making clicks inside a .swf file?

Tags: javascript, click, flash

First of all, it is possible?

Second, make something like coordinates in JS. For instance, 300 margin-top, 500 margin-left; make a click with the same effects and values than a normal mouse track in a laptop click.

Last, I don't mean onclick="", onmousedown="" etc. what I'm saying is an action/effect of a user click.

Thanks.
PS: if JS can't make this, another method can be done will be?

Comment: You can communicate between JS and AS using `ExternalInterface`. If it's not your `swf` you can't trigger a `click` event within AS.

Answer (score 0):

.swf objects are mostly a blackbox for javascript.  You can "listen" to some stuff in some cases (to an extent, things like when a video is played/stopped etc..but this is not 100% for all browsers/versions, and also depends on how the .swf object is invoked).  But "listening" general "actions" within a .swf is not possible with javascript.  Depending on what you want to do, you can effectively get the same thing..sometimes...like for instance, detecting a position inside a .swf object someone clicked...if you add an invisible html layer over the object, you can look for some things like clicks and even positions (in some cases).

But overall, the only real accurate way to do it is to add tracking/listening functions within the .swf object itself (which means you will need access to the .fla source file to add and re-compile to .swf).  And you use ActionScript for that (Flash's scripting language).  But you CAN make external js calls from within .swf object, if you need to pass info to js. But again, this involves putting code inside the .swf